# implememting iAd into my app

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, iad

I have put ad banners in all of my views, I haven't yet added any code. I was sure you needed code for your ads to load, but my app is loading ads across all views in my tab bar application.

Is there anything else i need to do or are the ads in my app running correctly (considering all i have done is added the iAd framework and put banners in every view)?

Comment: Well, have you checked the docs? If I remember correctly, you are going to want to code the ability to hide the banners when there is no internet connection, otherwise you will have white strips across your screen, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Why not watch this tutorial on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQYB63cXgfM